# Load whole widget area in WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, megamenu

I want to create very variable mega menu in WordPress. The idea is to use standard WP menu (register_nav_menus function) and new Gutenberg widgets. I created a main menu & widget area "mega-menu-1". Then I filled this widget area with various widgets (blocks) such as columns, images, paragraphs etc.

Now I would like to assign this menu to the first (or any other) item in the main menu. And I have no idea how. I didn't even find any tutorial doing this. There are some solutions for loading widgets "under" menu items, such as [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-widget-in-navigation/). But it just takes one particular widget and load it under the menu item. But I need to load whole widget area.

I guess it can somehow be done with the walker parameter in wp_nav_menu() function but I still need to be pushed the right direction :).

Is there please any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is what you need - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/

Answer (score 0):

First we need to extend Walker_Nav_Menu.
Since you want to be in any item you want i would recommend using class to trigger.

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
        // Check if the menu item has a specific class
        if (in_array('widget-area', $item->classes)) {
            
            ob_start();
            dynamic_sidebar('mega-menu-1');
            $sidebar_output = ob_get_clean();
            
            $output .= $sidebar_output;
        }
        
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args, $id);
    }
}
```

In your menu you have to add `walker` param to use this `Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu` .

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'your_menu_location',
    'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
));
```